# How to connect mysql to DevExpress ASPxScheduler without SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, mysql, devexpress, sqldatasource

I have an ASP.net project I'm looking at and they want to use MySQL.  I'm used to SQL server but using mySQL shouldn't be a problem.

Normally the control would like a SqlDataSource to bind to but that's not available with MySQL (from other posts on this site).

What's the best way to connect MySQL and the DevExpress ASPxScheduler so that you can create appointments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not an ObjectDataSource and write the data layer?  Or use LLBLGen, I think it works just fine with MySQL.  The one caveat I've seen is that the MySQL ODBC and ADO drivers have issues with metadata.

Answer (score 1):

I did end up using the objectdatasource and the ObjectCreated method and wrote the datalayer to insert records into the mysql database.  I've included my code just incase someone needs some help with some of the logic.

```
protected void appointmentsDataSource_ObjectCreated(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ObjectInstance = new CustomEventDataSource(GetCustomEvents());
    }

  public void InsertAppointment()
    {

        //need to reformat the dates
        string tempStartDate;
        string tempStartMinutes;

        if (appointmentobject.Start.Minute.ToString().Length == 1)
        {
            tempStartMinutes = "0" + appointmentobject.Start.Minute.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            tempStartMinutes = appointmentobject.Start.Minute.ToString();
        }

        tempStartDate = AppointmentObject.Start.Year + "-"
            + AppointmentObject.Start.Month + "-"
            + appointmentobject.Start.Day + " "
            + appointmentobject.Start.Hour + ":"
            + tempStartMinutes;

        string tempEndDate;
        string tempEndMinutes;

        if (appointmentobject.End.Minute.ToString().Length == 1)
        {
            tempEndMinutes = "0" + appointmentobject.End.Minute.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            tempEndMinutes = appointmentobject.End.Minute.ToString();
        }

        tempEndDate = AppointmentObject.End.Year + "-"
            + AppointmentObject.End.Month + "-"
            + appointmentobject.End.Day + " "
            + appointmentobject.End.Hour + ":"
            + tempEndMinutes;

        //TODO Add CustomField : Need to add to this Insert Statement

        //Change the appointment subject
        string NewSubject = AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldFirstName"]
            + ", " + AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldLastName"]
            + ", " + AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldClassID"]
            + ", " + AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldPhoneNumberDay"];

        string mySQLQueryString = @"INSERT INTO appointment (StartDate,EndDate,Subject,Status,Description,label,location,Type,FirstName,
            LastName,PhoneNumberDay,PhoneNumberEvening,DriversLicenseNumber,Email,RentalCar,Payment,ConfirmationNumber,
            PermitNumber,ClassID,CreateDate,CreateUser,NoticeToReport) 
            VALUES('" + tempStartDate + "','"
            + tempEndDate + "', '"
            //+ AppointmentObject.Subject + "',"
            + NewSubject + "',"
            + AppointmentObject.StatusId + ",'"
            + AppointmentObject.Description + "',"
            + AppointmentObject.LabelId + ", '"
            + AppointmentObject.Location + "',"
            + "0, '" //type
            + AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldFirstName"] + "','" 
            + AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldLastName"] + "','"
            + AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldPhoneNumberDay"] + "','"
            + AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldPhoneNumberEvening"] + "','"
            + AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldDriversLicenseNumber"] + "','"
            + AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldEmail"] + "',"
            + AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldRentalCar"] + ","
            + AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldPayment"] + ",'"
            + AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldConfirmationNumber"] + "','"
            + AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldPermitNumber"] + "',"
            + AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldClassID"] + ", '"
            //ignore create date for now.
            //+ AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldCreateDate"] + "', '"
            + "2009-01-01 12:00', '"
            + AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldCreateUser"] + "', "
            + AppointmentObject.CustomFields["fldNoticeToReport"] + ")";

        MySqlConnections test = new MySqlConnections();
        test.InsertRow(mySQLQueryString);

    }

public class MySqlConnections
{
    private static string DriverConnectionString = "Database=driverexam;Data Source=localhost;User Id=ART;Password=art01";

    public DataSet SelectRows(DataSet dataset, string query, string tablename)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(DriverConnectionString);

        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        adapter.Fill(dataset, tablename);

        conn.Close();
        return dataset;
    }

    public bool InsertRow(string query)
    {
     //   MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(DriverConnectionString);

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

        conn.ConnectionString = DriverConnectionString;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Success Occurred ");
        } //end of try
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error Occurred - " + ex.Message);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```